# SimpleXML, selecting node using child index with bracket syntax

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm using SimpleXML to pull in a XML feed. I need to grab the second node with the same name.

Feed example is:

```
<parent-node>
    <child-node>
        <the-node>
            <the-target>Text</target>
        </the-node>
        <the-node>
            <the-target>Text</target>
        </the-node>
    </child-node>
</parent-node>
```

Since the nodes I am targeting use hyphens, I need to use bracket syntax

`$item->{'parent-node'}->{'child-node'}->{'the-node'}`
This will grab the first `<the-node>`

When using the bracket syntax, I cannot select the second `<the-node>`'s `<the-target>`  using any of the following...

`$item->{'parent-node'}->{'child-node'}->{'the-node[2]'}->{'the-target'}`

`$item->{'parent-node'}->{'child-node'}->{'the-node'[2]}->{'the-target'}`

`$item->{'parent-node'}->{'child-node'}->{'the-node'}[2]->{'the-target'}`

My question is, how do I target childIndex while using the bracket syntax to grab the second `<the-node>`'s `<target>`?

**--- UPDATES ---**

After some of the answers, I have tried the following with no luck

`$item->{'parent-node'}->{'child-node'}->{'the-node'}[1]->{'the-target'}`

`$item->{'parent-node'}->{'child-node'}->{'the-node'}->{'the-target'}[1]`

`$item->{'child-node'}->{'the-node'}->{'the-target'}[1]`

Comment: Can you share what you've tried and how it failed?

Comment: just so you know you will want to access the child nodes as if they were an array, ie indexing starts at `0`, Have you tried to use `[1]` instead of `[2]`? This one is the right syntax: `$item->{'parent-node'}->{'child-node'}->{'the-node'}[2]` btw.

Answer (score 0):

[SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) stores sibling nodes as if they were an array. This usually indicates that the values are stored with a 0-based index, ie. the first value in the array starts at index `0`.

So in this case, the 2nd sibling node is only accessible using the index `1` instead of `2`.

Also the root-level node does not have to be traversed into by default (unless you omitted some other XML or are using some non-default settings).

Try this:

```
// Will grab the 2nd <the-node/>
$node = $item->{'child-node'}->{'the-node'}[1];
```

Depending on if your initial code did work without the array access, you can try this too:

```
// Testing locally I was not able to use this and got an error
// But maybe things are omitted in your question.
$node = $item->{'parent-node'}->{'child-node'}->{'the-node'}[1];
```

Comment: As a clarification:SimpleXMLElement does not store them - it provides access by implementing specific interfaces. `ArrayAccess` allows to use the bracket/array syntax, `Traversable` allows `foreach` loops. You can implement these interfaces into your own classes as well.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax looks like the following:

```
$item->{'child-node'}->{'the-node'}[0]; // First the-node
$item->{'child-node'}->{'the-node'}[1]; // Second the-node
```

If `parent-node` is the root element of all others, you cannot access it explicitly.

```
$item->{'parent-node'}->{'child-node'}->{'the-node'}[0];
```

The above code will result in error saying "Trying to get property of non-object".

Since `parent-node` is the top root element, you cannot access it explicitly.

Only the immediate child element of the top root element will be available to access in the SimpleXMLElement object.